# why output this result when I make break to label in iteration?

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie of javascript, and I certainly coundn't understand this output when I learn `for statement`..

```
foo: for(var i=0; i<3; i++){                                                                 
    console.log(i);
    if(i==1){
        break foo;
    }   
}
```

and I get some print like this..

```
0
1
```

to be honest, I dont know what happend here, I think that may throw error here because too deep iteration may be caused..

I want to get this result actually

```
0
1
0
1
0
1

...
```

maybe it's a stupid question, but I indeed want to get answer.

could anybody help me..

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I couldn't understand why that I can't get print like `0 1 0 1 0 1` and so on when I break label..

Comment: you break the loop, so it breaks, why would it restart if you don't tell it to restart ?

Comment: the structure does not fit your needs. in this case a infinite loop will do. `var v=0; while (true) {console.log(v); v=1-v;} But i do not recommend that without a suitable exit condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){                                                                 
    console.log(i);
    if(i==1){
        break foo;
    }   
}
```

You are running a for `loop` which is iterating from 0 to 3 (excluded).

in each iteration it `print` the value of i.

if value of i is 1 then it `break` from loop

```
first iteration: i=0; print 0 continue as 0 != 1

second iteration: i=1 print 1 break as 1 == 1
```

lean more about [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: I break label `foo`, why it print `0 1`  and over, I think it may continue exec `foo` label and print `0 1 0 1 0 1`  and so on ..

Comment: @E_Jovi read what [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) does...

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is trying to output `i` while it is less than 3 and increment it by one for every iteration.

the `if (i == 1)` statement is `true` in the second iteration so the `break` gets executed which "exits" the loop.

Comment: `break [Label];` as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) stated.

Comment: my bad. w3schools didn't mention that :) Fixing. Thanx

Comment: why it can't enter label `foo` and restart to print `0 1`?

Comment: It goes like this: i = 0. Output i. check if i is 1 (no). ignore break. increment i to 1 (second iteration). output i. check if i is 1 (yes). break (kill the for loop, not only current iteration). So i is never incremented or outputted again. That's why you only get 0 and 1 from first and second iteration before the loop is killed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does:

- print i
- then break

it will print `0 1` and then break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

- Actually **break** statement is used to get out of the loop.
- As we know earlier **for** loop loops execution until condition (here `i<3`) is true. if the condition gets false then it terminates ie., when the i is incremented to 3.
- But, the **if** condition to be checked is `i==1` so whenever i is incremented to 1 the **for** loop gets terminated by break statement.
- Each time the incremented value of **i** is printed in the console of the browser as a log. until the termination.

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop will do it.

```
var v = 0;
while (true) { // <-- this runs forever!
    console.log(v);
    v ^= 1;
}
```

or with a limit of 1000 loops

```js
var v = 1000;
while (v) {
    out(v % 2);
    v--;
}

// just for dispaying the result
function out(s) {
    var descriptionNode = document.createElement('div');
    descriptionNode.innerHTML = s + '<br>';
    document.getElementById('out').appendChild(descriptionNode);
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```